# Regional usage of "Violet" and "Purple"

Tags: american-english, british-english, australian-english, colors

I am looking to describe a flower such as the one in the following picture for a game:

[image: Violet Flower]

After showing the game to a number of beta testers, I noted that about half of them were fine with "violet" while the other half seemed confused by the term and insisted it was "purple".

After doing some research, it turns out that the definitions for these terms are (roughly):

- Purple: "A color between red and blue"
- Violet: "Light with a wavelength between 380nm and 450nm"

Those definitions overlap.
It seems to me (subjectively) that Australians and British are in favor of the term "Purple", while US Americans prefer "Violet". However, I was unable to find any statistical proof or study on the subject.

Question: What is an adequate word to describe the flower above to the majority of native English speakers?

Comment: *Purple* has got many different shades, while *violet* is a bluish purple. That's why I'd describe this flower as violet. I'm not sure however whether all native speakers would agree.

Comment: From what little Crayola-based knowledge I've retained, I'd agree with Irene that Violet is a bluer hue.

Comment: actually, they don't overlap at all. Purple is not a color between red (~700nm) and blue(~450nm) - yellow (~570nm) is. Purple is a mix of red and blue, which omits yellow, green, orange etc. OTOH violet may be perceived as closer to red, but is a color all by itself, in the range you gave.

Comment: My impression is that in popular usage in America, *purple* is a basic color used to describe all colors between red and blue. *Violet* is used for a range of shades of purple closer to the blue end of the range. Think *blue* and *ultramarine*. In fact, this matches your dictionary definitions, since the reddish end of the purples don't correspond to any single wavelengths of light.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yellow is a spectral color lying between red and blue; so is green, and orange, and nearly everything else. Violet, on the other hand, is a shorter spectral frequency than blue. Violet lies between blue and ultraviolet on the spectrum.  And purple isn’t a spectral color at all, but rather an admixture of red and blue. One can use red and blue light together to create a metameric match for spectral violet.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm not talking about wavelengths, but perception, e.g. on the [color wheel](http://www.colormatters.com/color-and-design/basic-color-theory).

Comment: @PeterShor Magenta and pink are both technically purples, while violet is not. People who actually work with color professionally/scientifically talk about these things in a more precise and particular manner than a 4-year-old might use.

Comment: @tchrist: Only by the technical definition not in popular use.

Comment: @PeterShor “Technical” definitions happen to matter to technical people. Commoners are always sloppy with language, conflating things that any specialist would cringe at. I’m sure we can find ideas from your own field that make you cringe when the ignorant get them all screwed up.

Comment: Quick question: This appears to be the kind of flower called a *violet.* Did you ask the testers about the color or what kind of flower? (It isn't clear from your question what they were actually asked.)

Comment: According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple), *purple* has one definition in common English usage, a second definition in color theory, and a third definition among artists.

Comment: I've always interpreted "violet" as being a specific shade of "purple".

Comment: @JLB The pictured blossom is *Vinca minor*, which is in a completely different family from anything in *Viola*.

Comment: @HotLicks Purple is made up of red and blue, but violet is of shorter wavelengths than blue and contains no red at all. Again, metameric lookalikes are also possible, which is what happens with an RGB display. However, reality can make true violet; there are LEDs of this frequency one can purchase.

Comment: It's true that the technical use of "violet" is as a spectral color, which looks rather like a bluish purple. However, to complicate the matter, I have found that some people in fact use the term "violet" to refer to a reddish purple! It's not a very basic color term.

Comment: Yet another use: the web color "Violet" has the same proportion of red and blue as "Purple" does, but it is lighter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names

Comment: @tchrist - You can say that violet contains no red, but keep in mind that human vision is based on the RGB receptor scheme, and many different combos of wavelengths may appear to be the same to the (normal) human eye.  (If this were not the case then color photography as we know it would be impossible.)  One can insist that "violet" is a certain wavelength, but that is a purely mechanical definition that does not reflect what people actually see.  (If it were true that violet is a specific wavelength then the above flower could not possibly be "violet".)

Comment: @HotLicks Um, and what do you think I meant by metameric lookalikes, eh? Everything you just said is contained within that.  Well, except the part of that not being able to be a metameric equivalent of violet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here in the U.S., I think most speakers would almost always use *purple*.

Why? For one, there is a flower called a *violet*, so folks are less likely to describe a **different** flower as *violet*. The [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purple%20clematis,violet%20clematis,purple%20tulips,violet%20tulips,%20purple%20hibiscus,%20violet%20hibiscus&year_start=1840&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) below supports my claim:

[image]

For another, when describing just about [any object of that color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCR5D.png), I think most people (except perhaps physicists) use *purple* in conversation, rather than *violet* (although the it's not like the latter is never used).

Comment: Photographers know the difference between purple and violet.  There is no purple in a rainbow, only violet.

Comment: +1 for the potential confusing surrounding 'violet' as a flower and a colour. If you showed them a different object with the same colour I suspect your results would be different.

Comment: I know lots of violet flowers, including the pictured *Vinca minor*, sometimes called *periwinkle* in the Common Tongue. Which of course gave rise to yet another color-name. Plus there's the familiar "roses are red, violets are blue" rhyme, from which a lot of people think of violets as being blue (as so many indeed are).